# Hardened app frameworks that actively TDD/unit test against OWASP top 10?

Tags: security, tdd, owasp

Are there any open source web frameworks that actively protect against the [OWASP Top 10 Security Vulnerabilities](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project)?

#### A framework that satisfies this requirement should include the following

- Can pass penetrations testing tools like [OWASP Zap Core](https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy)
- Supports standard authentication flows such as create new account, forgot password, login, etc?
- Is open source

The intent being to build an application that is secure from the ground up, with best practices already applied.

To me, the programming language is less important here than having these important lessons applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Electrode](http://www.electrode.io/docs/why_use_electrode.html), opensourced by Walmart as the backend app framework they use for walmart.com